# Problems with setting up git workspace?

Tags: git, github, bash, github-for-windows

I can't figure it out why my **.bash_profile** filename is not appearing ??

Please anybody help me out with this. If you need any further info then you can ask me I will give you all.

Comment: it's a hidden file. if you are using the command line try typing in ls -la and you should see it.............or if you are using windows then google 'how to view hidden files' and you should see it. HTH

Comment: What do you mean by _"hidden"_? Not showing on the file explorer or `git` does not detect it or what exactly. Please be more specific.

Comment: "_not appearing_" where?

Comment: No,I have created it but in the place of filename nothing is showing...and in place of filetype it is showing BASH_PROFILE File... please anybody give suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Try, in a bash session:

```
cd 
ls -alrth
```

If you don't see a.bash_profile there... that simply means you have to create it.
Generally, you would create a `.bashrc`, not a `.bash_profile`: see "[What is the difference between `.bash_profile` and `.bashrc`?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/51038)".
`.bash_profile` is executed for login shells, and you don't have to "login" here. A `.bashrc` is enough.